# Script to convert dokuwiki syntax to mediawiki

Tags: dokuwiki, wikimedia

Does someone knows a script to convert a file containing text formatted using the dokuwiki syntax to a text formatted using the wikimedia syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any of them, but (apparently, I have not used it) with [this](https://github.com/ludoza/DokuWiki-to-Markdown-Converter) you can convert a docuwiki document in Markdown, and thus with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) you can convert it in Mediawiki syntax.